# TypeError while trying to print a dataframe in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, typeerror

I have an example dataframe defined like this in python:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
  'col1': ['Item0', 'Item0', 'Item1', 'Item1'],
  'col2': ['Gold', 'Bronze', 'Gold', 'Silver'],
  'col3': [1, 2, np.nan, 4]
   })
```

when I try to print the dataframe df in jupyter notebook by simply typing 
df in jupyter and executing it I am getting an error:

**TypeError: The numpy boolean negative, the `-` operator, is not supported, use the `~` operator or the logical_not function instead.**

I have tried print(df), converting to html table and printing it, display(df) all are showing the same error.

PS: print(df) or just df were working perfectly fine in jupyter a few weeks back.

Comment: You've probably assigned something incorrect to `df` what does `type(df)` show? Also try restarting your kernel as it looks like you have some incorrect state

Comment: 100% agree with @EdChum. First step is to restart your kernel (or, to be extra safe, jupyter). Second step is to check the type of your `df`.

Comment: type(df) shows as : pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

Comment: and I restarted the kernel  still the same error

Comment: ya even I guess @EdChum is right. I am getting this error only when I run the following program on jupyter running on docker on server. When I executed the same program in the jupyter running on my local machine it works just fine.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using iloc,

```
    df.iloc[0:5] #this will show first 5 rows of the dataframe
```

for more details visit http://www.shanelynn.ie/select-pandas-dataframe-rows-and-columns-using-iloc-loc-and-ix/

Answer (score 2):

It helped me to upgrade from pandas 0.13 to 0.20.3.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this error in a different setting, and I think the underlying issue is incompatibility with Numpy 1.13, with the (interim) fix being to reinstall with Numpy 1.12.

The change in behavior that's causing the error is that Numpy now throws an error if you try and negate a boolean:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/release.html#deprecationwarning-to-error

> DeprecationWarning to error: negative(bool_), TypeError when negative applied to booleans.

Comment: I cannot print(df) or df in Jupyter, or in python. The error msg was: TypeError: reduce() takes at most 5 arguments (6 given). Moving numpy from 1.15 to 1.14 solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Try editing the file it gives error. I had a similar issue pointing to file series.py in my python packages at line ~1800 had to manually edit
`good = -bad` to `good = ~bad`

Surprisingly even when I commented the first line to add the second it game me an error saying - is not supported ...

After editing it manually everything looks fixed.